# For loops crashing my android app

Tags: java, android, for-loop, arraylist

I am writing a code relating to finding prime numbers, and it was working great until I realized I needed to divide each number in the ArrayList by all the numbers that came before it (ex: if the ArrayList was {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} I want to divide 5 by 4, 3, 2, and 1; 4 by 3, 2, and 1, etc.)

Because the contents of the ArrayList vary depending on what the user of the app inputted, I figured the best way to go about doing what I needed is this:

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends MainActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    int limit = Integer.parseInt(message);

    ArrayList<Integer> finalPrime = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> primeNumber = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= limit; i++) {

        if (!(i % 2 == 0 || i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0 || i % 7 == 0))
            primeNumber.add(i);
    }

    for (int k = 0; k <= limit; k++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= k; j++) {
            int a = primeNumber.get(k) % primeNumber.get(j);
            if (!(a == 0)) {
                finalPrime.add(k);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

        String primes = primeNumber.toString();

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(primes);
    }
}
```

'message' is the number that the user inputs into the textbox at the beginning, which sets the limit for how high they want the prime numbers to count up to.

Android Dev Studio's IDE isn't saying there are any bugs in my code, and logically it should work, but when I try to run it in the Device Simulator, the app crashes after I click the 'send' button, which then switches the activities to DisaplayMessageActivity.

I took out the nested for loops, and the code ran perfectly and without error, so my questions are: (a) is there a more efficient way to go about doing what I aim to do; and (b) why isn't my code working?

Edit: Here is the LogCat at the time of the crash

```
06-20 13:09:57.459 12826-12826/com.example.name.primenumberfinder E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                          Process: com.example.name.primenumberfinder, PID: 12826
                                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.name.primenumberfinder/com.example.name.primenumberfinder.DisplayMessageActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
                                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
                                                                                              at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
                                                                                              at com.example.name.primenumberfinder.DisplayMessageActivity.onCreate(DisplayMessageActivity.java:32)
                                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
                                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Comment: Please post the logcat at the time of crash too

Comment: The number of elements in `primeNumbers` is significantly less than `limit`. Array out of bounds exception.

Comment: You are getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` in `DisplayMessageActivity.java` line no :32

Comment: Also, 1 is not a prime number.

Comment: you need to keep the size of the two arraylists in mind while running a for loop. Also, I don't really like the logic for prime number caluclation. Checkout this link for a more efficient way of finding prime numbers https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-determine-a-prime-number-in-java/

Comment: IT'S NOT THE LOOP that's causing the crash. Look at the LOG
ARRAY INDEX OUT OF BOUNDS
You are trying to insert an item at `n+1`'th position where `n` is your limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code for dividing each number in array list with rest of the items(number). Here's the code

```
int n =  primeNumber.size();
for (int k = 0; k <n-1; k++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <n-k-1; j++) {
            int a = primeNumber.get(j) % primeNumber.get(j+1);
            if (a != 0) {
                finalPrime.add(k);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```